# puncycode.toASCII is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пожалуйста, помогите

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="Utf-8">
    <script data-main="findem" src="require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="findem.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

собираю файл browserify, чтобы использовать модули node через браузер

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://1@gmail.com:7777@smtp.gmail.com');
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"John" <John@gmail.com>',
    to: '2221@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello ',
    text: 'Hello11',
    html: '<b>Hello22</b>'
};


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

сама ошибка:

```
url.js:295 Uncaught TypeError: punycode.toASCII is not a function

Url.parse   @   url.js:295 

urlParse    @   url.js:106

module.exports.parseConnectionUrl   @   shared.js:18

module.exports.createTransport  @   nodemailer.js:37

253.nodemailer  @   main.js:4

s   @   _prelude.js:1

e   @   _prelude.js:1

(anonymous function)    @   _prelude.js
```

Никак не могу разобраться, что я сделал не так?!

Comment: Я не понял. Вы хотите письма прямо из браузера слать что ли?